# How to handle long running jobs that are posted to a service bus with only 5min peek lock

Tags: azure, message-queue, servicebus

What do people tend to do when they have a design that put jobs on a service queue or topic that takes longer then the 5min max of peeklock?

I have been using the OnMessage(...) async messagepump of service bus and is wondering if thats not such a good idea after also since if I start moving the jobs to a table while processing them, then the messagepump will just empty the queue and I just have the problem elsewhere of making sure my jobs are scheduled even between servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a long running message processing workflow the you can check the lockedUntilUtc property of the message and call RenewLock at the appropriate time.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.brokeredmessage.renewlock.aspx

in the next release of SDK the OnMessage processing loop will automatically do that for you so that convenience API is always a good idea to use.

Comment: How far are we from getting new release of SDK ? wonder if I can wait it out or implement some renew lock for now.

Comment: Pretty soon, no official date though :)

Comment: Cool. Just did a simple renewing the lock for now and can remove that when you guys releases.

Comment: could you state for wich version number you have/or going to put this into ? Hard to keep track about if its already there by now or not.